# How to correctly upgrade STL from the source of GCC

Tags: gcc, installation, stl, g++, debian

I built gcc/g++ 10.5.0 from source, because I guessed that v10.5.0 is more stable than v10.2.1 that is the latest version I can get from the official apt repository of Debian-11.

The making scripts that come with gcc source are very perfect, they not only make a set of compilers, but also make STL (libstdc++6.so, I guess it is STL implement) and many other libs.

It is easy to replace the compilers binaries, even more I can also add a `update-alternatives` to let these two versions existing side by side.

But I want to use the new libs in my producing env (Debian-11 server, no developing tool), since that upgrading compiler merely can improve the code of my app, but can do nothing with STL that already existing on the producing env.

Because the major versions of both are all v10, I guess the API would not change (more possibly with bugfix). Indeed their names are exactly same, eg. `libstdc++.so.6.0.28`, `libatomic.so.1.2.0`, `libitm.so.1.0.0`, and so on.

**Question 1:**

How to correctly upgrade/replace the STL in my producing env?
If I simply replace them with my own, does this influence the other app of the producing env even the whole system?

**Question 2:**

Which files/libs are necessary when making a .deb package that is intend to replace STL?